How to get TLS v1.0 working in a Electron based application?
We are trying to write a media application in electron and are encountering a problem we have no clue  if it's possible to solve.
We are loading streams with m3u8 content and some streams are still using TLS v1.0. Now the electron browserwindow is using chromium. And they have dropped support for TLS v1.0.
Now we are struggling on how to tackle this issue. (We prototyped a Java application first and that one is working for TLS v1.0 but we wanted to use electron)
We tried running a proxy server but it will request firewall access on run. So this is not really ideal for using in a media player.
We tried all security flags on electron without succes. So our guess is that we should look at older versions of Chromium but that would leave a window for security problems.
So now our options  can think of are depleted and are desperately looking for a solution. Maybe somebody here has an idea. Or maybe we should switch platforms all together and continue the Java solution.
Thanks in advance!

TLSv1.0 is no longer secure and is disabled by default for good reason. Is it your stream or someone else's that requires it? If it's yours, why can't you fix that? If it's someone else's, whose is it?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your reply. It's somebody elses we have no clue of who it is unfortunately. We use hls.js for the fetching of the stream and it gives an error on xhr request.

Can you post the URL of it?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica This is the host https://pdvyaqdr52539852z.f15s10.fokos.me connecting to it gives an error.
